# When are the upvotes counted for a tag badge

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

- The question has a set of tags when it is asked.
- When you answer the question it may have changed.
- At the time you recieve an upvote it could be different again.
- Then there is the current state of tags on the question.

My question is, is it important to check that the tags are correct before answering a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not important to check that the tags are correct before answering a question - because badges themselves aren't that important, IMO.

If you consistently answer well in a topic, you will eventually get a badge for that tag. Could you maybe get there a *tiny bit earlier* by checking for tags? Maybe. Or maybe the extra time taken to check the tags will let others get in their answers earlier, possibly costing you votes.

Why does it really matter? Isn't the point to get accurate answers for those asking the questions (and future researchers)? Badges are a bit of fun, not the main goal.

EDIT: Changed tags for question to include "badges" and "tags" to make sure I get those badges that bit sooner...

(Seriously, it's worth editing a question's tags *for the sake of accurate classification* - not to get you more badges.)

Comment: You mean I've been playing this game wrong the entire time? Thanks for ruining it all for me, Jon.

Comment: Race you to 1000 ;)

Comment: I have a feeling you'd win. I did a dance yesterday just because I managed to pass you again on gold badges.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for your answer, I agree with you, however without the badges and reputation stackoverflow would not be nearly as addictive as it is.

Comment: @Shiraz: I completely agree that badges and rep are a good thing in general - but when you get to the stage of working out whether to edit the question before or after writing your answer, that's taking it a little too far.

Comment: The question still stands though: *when are the upvotes counted for a tag badge?*